# Show multiple variables from different tables in a Select drop down using Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a list of users and a list of locations for those users -

I wish to create a select that shows the User and they'r first address

so
     Mr Smith : London

To achieve this I've created

```
@callers=User.order(:name).includes(:locations).all
```

then on the page

```
<div class="field">
          <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
          <%= f.select(:user_id, validate: false) do %>
          <option value="">New Contact</option>
            <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@callers, :id, " : #{:name} : #{:town}") %>
          <% end %>

</div>
```

However the SQL statement isn't joining the tables, its collecting all the Users variables AND a separate SQL collects all the Locations matching the joining ID's

Is there a simpler way to resolve this than writing my own SQL joining statement ? what is wrong with my logic here ?

Comment: Removed the Python tag - there's not a single parrot (even a dead one) to be found here ;)

Comment: Et tu Brutas ? - Sorry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that the ~User had a collection of addresses, so simply called locations.first

```
     <div class="field">
      <%= f.label :user_id %><br>
      <%= f.select(:user_id, validate: false) do %>
      <option value="00" >New Contact</option>
        <%  @callers.each do |w| %>
              <option value="<%=w.id%>"><%=w.name%> : <%= w.locations.first.city%></option>
         <% end %>
      <% end %>

     </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can save all this information in a join table

```
users = User.order(:name).joins(:locations)
```

users will be an array like this

```
[#<User id: 3, email: "leon_padberg@cain.net", created_at: "2017-08-31 07:45:30", updated_at: "2017-08-31 07:45:30", is_moderator: nil, is_admin: nil, reputation: 70, username: "adrianna_bailey">,
 #<User id: 3, email: "leon_padberg@cain.net", created_at: "2017-08-31 07:45:30", updated_at: "2017-08-31 07:45:30", is_moderator: nil, is_admin: nil, reputation: 70, username: "adrianna_bailey">]
```

You can display the `@user` with `users[i]` where `i=0` or `i=1`

You can display the `location` with `users[i].locations`, you can order them with `users[i].locations.order(:id)` and select the `first` entry

Comment: This would lead me to something like this on the page...

              <option value="">New Contact</option>

                <%  @callers.each do |w| %>
  
                  <option value="<%=w.id%>"><%=w.name%> : <%= w.locations.first.city%> </option>

                <% end %>
   
           <% end %>

But wouldn't the overhead be ridiculous ? this will crumble when the table scales up ?

Comment: @StevenMoffat I ll try later to give you a better answer but at the following link you can read more about queries on ruby on rails. I think what you want is building an array that has those entries you need to display on the table.  So maybe a `select_all` or `pluck` could work out guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html

Comment: Thanks - the link was exactly what I needed to understand the Rails query structure